# Oracle Bulk update with same column

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I have employee table ,where all of the employee ID got changed , this table is history table and having active indicator , new employee ID got changed and active indicator is updated with 'Y' but now i wanted to update all 'N' indicator emp id also with new employee id.i have more than 10000 emp and i am new to oracle , so just wanted to get help to get the table update

[sample table op](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5Rnv.png)

need bulk update Update SQL statement to update the emp id

Answer (score 0):

Use a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWID as rid,
         MAX(CASE active_code WHEN 'Y' THEN empid END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY uniq_id) AS new_empid
  FROM   table_name
) src
ON (src.rid = dst.ROWID AND dst.active_code = 'N')
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET  empid = new_empid;
```

Or a correlated `UPDATE`:

```sql
UPDATE table_name dst
SET empid = ( SELECT empid
              FROM   table_name src
              WHERE  src.uniq_id = dst.uniq_id
              AND    src.active_code = 'Y'
              AND    ROWNUM = 1 )
WHERE active_code = 'N';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (empid, active_code, uniq_id) AS
SELECT 1,   'Y', 123 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, 'N', 123 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, 'N', 123 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, 'N', 123 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, 'N', 123 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   'Y', 456 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200, 'N', 456 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200, 'N', 456 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200, 'N', 456 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200, 'N', 456 FROM DUAL;
```

Then, after the `MERGE` or `UPDATE`, the table contains:

| EMPID | ACTIVE_CODE | UNIQ_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Y | 123 |
| 1 | N | 123 |
| 1 | N | 123 |
| 1 | N | 123 |
| 1 | N | 123 |
| 2 | Y | 456 |
| 2 | N | 456 |
| 2 | N | 456 |
| 2 | N | 456 |
| 2 | N | 456 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NZ2KC-95)