# oracle cursor or loop statement for update

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, bulkupdate

I have employee table where it keep the history with Active data indicator , recently we have provided new Emp ID and the emp table got updated with active data indicator Y for all new employee ID update , where as old emp id  got 'N'

Now i wanted to update the old emp id with new emp id , i have around 10K records with this scenrio , so is there any way that i can update all old emp id with new id ? is there any way i can update them ? i wanted to update only emp id column

data there:

| Name | UNQ ID | EMP ID | Update date | Active Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sam D | q1212 | 12356 | 04/11/2022 | Y |
| Sam D | q1212 | 00123 | 03/13/2020 | N |
| Sam D | q1212 | 00123 | 12/12/2019 | N |

data i wanted to have:

| Name | UNQ ID | EMP ID | Update date | Active Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sam D | q1212 | 12356 | 04/11/2022 | Y |
| Sam D | q1212 | 12356 | 03/13/2020 | N |
| Sam D | q1212 | 12356 | 12/12/2019 | N |

Since i am new to oracle , i have no idea how to do that

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76557580/oracle-bulk-update-with-same-column

Answer (score -1):

Assuming `unq_id` uniquely identifies your employee, a simple update should suffice by getting the `emp_id` for the same `unq_id` where the flag is Y:

```
UPDATE employee e1
   SET emp_id = (SELECT MAX(e2.emp_id)
                   FROM employee e2
                  WHERE e2.unq_id = e1.unq_id
                    AND e2.active_data = 'Y')
 WHERE active_data = 'N'
```